# Styling and ordering CKEdtior custom toolbar plugin buttons

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor instance with a lot of custom plugins. My problem now is, I want to style these buttons appropriately on the toolbar. In the following picture, my 'custom plugin group' is all the way to the right (They may look like the default icons for save, maximize and exit but they are, and must be, custom plugins).

[image: Standard display]

However, this looks goofy. Most importantly, I'd like the [X] icon to be floating to the right, and be a non-grouped button. My config looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { <the standard toolbar button declarations> },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] }
      ]
    config.extraPlugins = 'save_btn,custom_max, close_btn';
 });
```

So I can order the plugins with the 'extra plugins', but I can't ungroup them. I'e tried using the toolbarGroups to change them, but the extraPlugins always seem to get dumped into 'other' no matter what. 
I've also tried adding them in seperate config.extraPlugins instances...but this only adds the first call.

I also tried setting this in the css declaration:

```
var active_editor = element.ckeditor(function(){ 
    $('.cke_button__close_btn').css({'margin-left':'10px'})
   });
```

But setting the margin/padding of this doesn't work. The style gets applied...but just pads the elements and doesn't actually separate them.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toolbar configuration (in your download: /samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html) to change the way that the items are grouped and ordered.

To apply custom styling to an element, you'll have to fire up your development tools and check how to adjust the styles of the elements according to your needs, then use javascript to modify those elements after CKEditor has been loaded